# Polars show_graph method

Tags: python-3.x, python-polars, rust-polars

I am starting to use Polars as a replacement for Pandas. I am very interested in using the show_graph() method to my team to show some of the benefits. One of the biggest benefits I can see is the use of scan_csv. However I am seeing some oddities that I cannot explain. I have the following code using the iris data set.

```
import polars as pl

x = pl.scan_csv('iris.csv')
x.show_graph()

x = pl.scan_csv('iris.csv').filter(pl.col('variety') == "Setosa").select("petal.length").sum()
x.show_graph()
```

I am getting random pi and sigma characters. Can anyone explain what the pi and sigma mean? In addition is there a way to ensure that the boxes expand to show all of the information (the csv scan box appears to be cut off in the second show_graph() call.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sigmas and pis aren't random. They're from SQL nomenclature. See [here](https://cs.nyu.edu/%7Ejcf/classes/CSCI-GA.2433-001_sp15/slides/session5/RelationalAlgebra-RelationalCalculus-SQL.pdf)

The sigma is a selection criteria and the pi is an attribute list.

As to the sizing, [the docs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/lazyframe/api/polars.LazyFrame.show_graph.html#polars.LazyFrame.show_graph) show there's a figsize parameter whose default is `(16.0, 12.0)` so maybe try with `(32.0, 12.0)` and try different settings there.

Comment: Thanks! I have never seen that nomenclature before.